# NSFetchedResultsController not showing all results

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

A bit of background info:
I'm grabbing data from a Ruby on Rails website, parsing its json, and assigning objects to Core Data objects. This is working well, and the rows are importing fine, with the exception that it doesn't yet check for duplicates (I haven't yet implemented that). So every time I launch the app, I get an extra 3 objects added.

I've setup a `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch all objects of my model:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"remote_id" ascending:YES]];
return [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

and In my table controller, I've added all the methods to pull data off from the FetchedResultsController into the table delegate methods.

The problem itself is, when doing a `NSFetchRequest` I get back all the objects in the array (there are around 60 at the moment), but the table is only showing 3 results. The (coincidently..?) same 3 results that are on my rails server.

I opened the database manually and edited a few of the 'duplicate' records to check whether it was doing some magical duplication checking and my manually edited records still aren't showing. At this point I'm lost. What could possibly be causing the results to filter down? The code shouldn't be aware of these models being duplicates in the first place. I just don't 
understand.

Edit----

More info:

My TableViewController is a subclass of the CoreDataTableViewController provided here from Standford (accompanying lecture videos are available on iTunes U, and are fantastic, by the way):
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall
(ctrl+f for CoreDataTableViewController.zip)

This deals with `performFetch` after assigning on the fetchedResultsController property setter
and simply calls

```
NSError *error;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]),  NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
//...
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and as for section and row count (returns 1 and 3):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm simply calling the following to retrieve each object

```
id myObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

edit 2 ----- Okay, here's actual code rather than me picking parts out:

In my `Registration+sync.m`:

```
+ (NSFetchRequest*)requestForAll {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"remote_id" ascending:YES]];
    return request;
}

+ (NSFetchedResultsController*)requestForAllResultsController {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [self requestForAll];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [DataController instance].database.managedObjectContext;
    return [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
}

+ (NSArray*)allObjects {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [self requestForAll];
    return [[DataController instance] fetch:request];
}
```

In DataController:

```
- (NSArray*)fetch:(NSFetchRequest*)request {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.database.managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    return [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

In the TableViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"rows: %d", [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects]);
    NSLog(@"all objects: %d", [[Registration allObjects] count]);
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}
```

prints out the following:

```
2012-10-09 15:22:04.211 MyApp[8279:c07] rows: 4
2012-10-09 15:22:04.214 MyApp[8279:c07] all objects: 68
```

Comment: It could be related to how or when you call `performFetch:` or it could be related to data source methods (`numberOfRowsInSection:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`).  Can you add some detail about those things?

Comment: I've updated the question with more details

Comment: Sorry, misleading title (edited). There is no predicate and is therefore supposed to fetch all of the model's rows.

Comment: One more thing I don't understand: you say "when doing a NSFetchRequest I get back all the objects in the array" but I don't see what array you're referring to.  Just before calling `reloadData`, perhaps logging the count of objects in each section would help.

Comment: No answers; just more questions....  This code: `NSStringFromClass([self class])` is executing inside a `Registration` method?  Is it the same context for both the 3 and 63 results?

Comment: edited more in the quested, read from 'edit 2 -----'

Comment: Ergh, I'm an idiot. The rows that get loaded into the table are those fetched from the remote server during the current session, not related to duplicate detection at all... Think the problem is simply a race condition with loading the database.